# Regex Operator in Validating HTML Tags

Tags: html, regex

I am following Regular Expression.info and see on their [samples page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html) an expression to match agains HTML tags, as follows:

```
([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>
```

What is the semantic effect of the part \b[^]?  I get its a word boundary but given what follows it what is the purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It matches anything extra (if it exists) up until the next occurrence of a ">" (closing HTML tag). This would capture stuff like `class="classname" id="idname"`. However, it would also capture any character you could think of, such as `•·°ÁÓ`, which may or may not be what you want. As always, a proper HTML parser is the way to go for parsing HTML.